# Using SolrPhpClient in Drupal

Tags: search

I am using SolrPhpClient with Drupal, and I want to use Drupal as higher-layer user-interface to be able to query and retrieve search results from Apache Solr.

I tried to use [this example](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/wiki/ExampleUsage) for testing if Drupal works with SolrPhpClient, but I am getting two errors:

> Deprecated function: Function split() is deprecated in ApacheSolr_Response->_construct() (line 117 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/apachesolr/SolrPhpClient/Apache/Solr/Response.php).
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in eval() (line 80 of /var/www/drupal/modules/php/php.module(75) : eval()'d code).

Have anyone used SolrPhpClient before? I have never used PHP, so I had a difficult time understanding it.

Comment: You have a whole lot of modules to integrate SOLR with Drupal (http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr). Is there any reason not to use them ?

Comment: I use all those modules, the problem is that I index a json file of size (1 GB) from my ubuntu terminal in to SOLR using CURL command. I am able to query it using "SOLR admin" but i am not able to do the same using drupal Search Engine. Do you think it is possible to query successfully using Drupal for a json file indexed in SOLR, because i am not able to make it work in Drupal, i am trying to use this way to query and retrieve results ... Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Anything that can be indexed by SOLR is searchable by Drupal SOLR module. I speak from experience : you can feed the SOLR index with anything you fancy, and make results come up in the Drupal search pages. This is more or less what happens when you implement multisite search.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my hopes were up after seeing your reply. So I need to use (search_api) & put my schema in the (schema.xml) file to make it work with drupal ? based on what you said i am thinking of tweaking the schema.xml to make it work .. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, it involves tweaking schema.xml, and implementing some hooks here and there. You'll find excellent documentation about it on d.o and elsewhere on the net, but it's way beyond the scope of this thread. Here's one about D7 port : http://drupal.org/node/1006994 (not ready yet, but the module is functional under D6).